# When does JSON_CONTAINS return 1 with 3rd argument omitted?

Tags: mysql, json

There is a `JSON_CONTAINS` function in MySQL with 3 arguments. [The documentation states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) that 3rd argument can be omitted and it will search in all paths then. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me

```
SET @j = '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": {"d": 4}}';
SET @j2 = '1';
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@j, @j2, '$.a'); # returns 1
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@j, @j2); # returns 0
```

Can you provide an sensible example, when `JSON_CONTAINS` return `1` with 3rd argument omitted?

Is it possible to search in all nodes of JSON?

Comment: [JSON_CONTAINS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) *Indicates by returning 1 or 0 whether a given candidate **JSON document** is contained within a target JSON document*. Minimal JSON document which contains the value which you're interested in is `'{"a":1}'`.

Comment: @Akina Numeric constant is also valid `JSON` document, for example `1` is a valid JSON document. How to test it's containment?

Comment: It is valid JSON document, this is true, but it is valid JSON document for JSON_CONTAINS() when you search in JSON array. Whereas you try to search in the object.

Comment: *How to test it's containment?* When you need to search for **numeric** value of the object property then the only way is to parse the object (use JSON_TABLE function) and test parsed separate values. Or you may use string, not JSON, search.